# Java BiConsumer<String, String> cons = (x,y) -> what next?

Tags: java

I want to make 2 strings uppercase with a use of BiConsumer

```
BiConsumer<String, String> cons = (x,y) -> ...?
```

Can you tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Can you clarify "make 2 strings uppercase"? You want to return each string in uppercase? Print them in uppercase? Concatenate them in uppercase? And have you tried?

Comment: A (Bi)Consumer doesn't return anything, so what do you want to do with the result of uppercasing these strings?

Comment: I want to print them in uppercase.

Comment: Do you know how to do that without a BiConsumer?

Comment: I want to do this with a use of BiConsumer as I wrote.

Comment: Ok, but knowing how to do it _without_ a BiConsumer is a prerequisite (or at least is 95% of the problem).

Comment: Can someone write the solution ? I want to do this with a use of BiConsumer.

Comment: Then just print them in upper case: `(x, y) -> System.out.println(/* strings in uppercase */);`...

Answer (score 1):

A `BiConsumer` is basically just a bit of code that accepts two inputs and returns nothing. A `BiConsumer<String, String>` is basically a method like this:

```
void aMethod(String a, String b) {
  // Do whatever with a and b.
}
```

You can assign this to a `BiConsumer` variable:

```
BiConsumer<String, String> cons = this::aMethod;
```

Or you can do it without explicitly declaring the method, but putting its body inline:

```
BiConsumer<String, String> cons = (a, b) -> {
  // Do whatever with a and b.
};
```

And if "do whatever" is a single statement (and isn't a `throw`), you can omit the `{}`:

```
BiConsumer<String, String> cons = (a, b) -> /* Do whatever with a and b. */;
```

The "do whatever" here is simply code. If you want to uppercase the strings and print them, just do that in exactly the same way as you would outside a `BiConsumer`. There's not really anything special or different about it because it's inside a `BiConsumer`.